# AWS Cloudfront + Load Balancer, url changes from main domain to load balancer subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system, load-balancing, amazon-elb, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

My setup is as follows:

1. user types example.com on the browser
2. request goes to AWS CloudFront, which redirects HTTP to HTTPS, and
   forwards the request to the AWS Elastic LoadBalancer
   (elb.example.com)
3. LoadBalancer forwards the request to the EC2 instance running PHP
   Laravel framework
4. EC2 responds normally
5. user views the page correctly at example.com with everything else
   transparent to him

All this is perfectly what I want, HOWEVER .....

- If the user navigates to any button on the page, the url on the
  browser will become elb.example.com (it should stay example.com)
- If I go to view page source, all the links to any button on the page
  has the base url of elb.example.com (it should be example.com)

The reason is because EC2 see the request coming from the load balancer so it assumes the base url is elb.example.com and generates all links accordingly.

How do make EC2 see the base url as example.com ?

Comment: Can you just use relative links rather than outputting absolute URLs?

Comment: This has been answered on StackOverflow [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38286901/aws-cloudfront-load-balancer-url-changes-from-main-domain-to-load-balancer-su](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38286901/aws-cloudfront-load-balancer-url-changes-from-main-domain-to-load-balancer-su)

Comment: Having just gone through this, all the other answers are either outdated, or way too vague to actually understand. Here's a walk-through: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69399672

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This behavior likely results from the fact that by default CloudFront sets the Host: HTTP request header to the origin hostname, in this case elb.example.com. The application then presumably generates links based on that hostname.

If, instead, you configure CloudFront to whitelist that header for forwarding to the origin, the Host header sent by the browser (example.com) will be sent on to the application by CloudFront, so the application should behave more like you'd expect and use that value when generating the links. With this, CloudFront still uses the origin server hostname to do the DNS lookup needed in order to establish the TCP connection to the origin (the ELB in this case), but stops injecting that hostname into the HTTP request headers.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesForwardHeaders

This has been answered by @michael-sqlbot [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38286901/aws-cloudfront-load-balancer-url-changes-from-main-domain-to-load-balancer-su/38288678#38288678)

Comment: Under "Cache Behavior/Whitelist Headers" I whitelisted Host, Origin and Referrer and it worked. Probably you can try to whitelist only Host.

Comment: Having just gone through this, all the other answers are either outdated, or way too vague to actually understand. Here's a walk-through: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69399672